# Passing Structure with UINT32 via Namedpipe between two C applications on Windows but getting empty buffer in client side

Tags: c, windows, named-pipes

I am passing a structure with 4 unsigned int values {0, 1, 2, 3}. But I am getting empty buffer in the client, it is printing the values {0, 0, 0, 0}. What am I doing wrong?

I am using Windows 10 with 64 bit OS.

I am passing the values between client and server applicaitons using namedpipes.

```
typedef struct _ObjectInfo
{
    UINT32 Height;
    UINT32 XCoordinate;
    UINT32 YCoordinate;
    UINT32 Width;
}ObjectInfo;
```

**Instructions:**

Run the client before the server.

- The Client comes up and waits for server to write something.
- The Server writes something and exits.
- The Client and Server code are independantly compilable.
- Client and Server programs run on the same system and communicate via namedpipe IPC.
- In Visual Studio, I have set Multibyte Character String setting.

**Here is the client code:**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

#define TestCoordinate_Pipe "\\\\.\\pipe\\TestCoordinates"
#define MESSAGE_MAX_LENGTH  1024

typedef struct _ObjectInfo
{
    UINT32 Height;
    UINT32 XCoordinate;
    UINT32 YCoordinate;
    UINT32 Width;
}ObjectInfo;

char* getObjectLocation(char* pipe)
{
    HANDLE hPipe;
    char buffer[MESSAGE_MAX_LENGTH] = { 0 };
    DWORD dwRead;
    hPipe = CreateNamedPipe(
        pipe,
        PIPE_ACCESS_DUPLEX,
        PIPE_TYPE_BYTE | PIPE_READMODE_BYTE | PIPE_WAIT,
        1,
        MESSAGE_MAX_LENGTH,
        MESSAGE_MAX_LENGTH,
        NMPWAIT_USE_DEFAULT_WAIT,
        NULL);
    while (hPipe != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
    {
        if (ConnectNamedPipe(hPipe, NULL) != FALSE)   // wait for someone to connect to the pipe
        {
            while (ReadFile(hPipe, buffer, sizeof(buffer) - 1, &dwRead, NULL) != FALSE);
            buffer[dwRead] = '\0';
            printf("Buffer: %s; buffsize %d", buffer, dwRead);
        }
        DisconnectNamedPipe(hPipe);
        hPipe = INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE;
    }
    return buffer;
}

int main()
{
    ObjectInfo objectInfo;
    char* buffer = getObjectLocation(TestCoordinate_Pipe);
    RtlCopyMemory(&objectInfo, buffer, sizeof(ObjectInfo));
    printf("\n\tHeight: %d;\t X-Coordinate: %d\t Y-Coordinate: %d\tWidth: %d",
        objectInfo.Height,
        objectInfo.XCoordinate,
        objectInfo.YCoordinate,
        objectInfo.Width);
}
```

**Here is the server code:**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <Windows.h>

#define TestCoordinate_Pipe "\\\\.\\pipe\\TestCoordinates"
#define MESSAGE_MAX_LENGTH  1024

typedef struct _ObjectInfo
{
    UINT32 Height;
    UINT32 XCoordinate;
    UINT32 YCoordinate;
    UINT32 Width;
}ObjectInfo;

void setObjectLocation(char* pipe, char* msg)
{
    HANDLE hPipe;
    DWORD dwWritten;

    hPipe = CreateFile(
        pipe,
        GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE,
        0,
        NULL,
        OPEN_EXISTING,
        0,
        NULL);
    if (hPipe != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
    {
        WriteFile(
            hPipe,
            msg,
            (DWORD)strlen(msg),
            &dwWritten,
            NULL);
        CloseHandle(hPipe);
    }
}

int main()
{
    ObjectInfo objectInfo;
    objectInfo.Height = 0;
    objectInfo.XCoordinate = 1;
    objectInfo.YCoordinate = 2;
    objectInfo.Width = 3;

    char msg[MESSAGE_MAX_LENGTH] = { 0 };
    RtlCopyMemory(msg, &objectInfo, sizeof(ObjectInfo));
    setObjectLocation(TestCoordinate_Pipe, msg);
}
```

Output:
[image]

Expected Output:

Height: 0;       X-Coordinate: 1         Y-Coordinate: 2        Width: 3

Please help me resolve this.

Comment: `getObjectLocation` is returning a pointer to a local array variable. That pointer becomes invalid as soon as the function returns. I suggest changing it to use a buffer passed in by the caller, like you do in the server.

Comment: @IanAbbott. I tried dynamic memory allocation and passing the buffer as a parameter. It is still printing the same output. If you observe, the print statement immediately after the read is giving NULL, not the return value from the function.

Comment: You are using `strlen` on something that isn't a null-terminated string.

Comment: Hi @RaymondChen, I tried two other options. Changed from strlen to `sizeof(ObjectInfo)`. Also I tried null terminating before write like so: `msg[sizeof(ObjectInfo)] = '\0';`. Both these options are not solving the problem

Comment: The code throws away the results of successful reads and only print the results of failed reads. That seems backwards. I think you would be well-served to step through the code line by line and check the return values of every function and the contents of every local variable.

Comment: Hi @RaymondChen, thank you. I have found the problem. I thought on these lines and realized that in the Read section also I had to use `sizeof(ObjectInfo)`. Let me post the solution

Answer (score 0):

Using `sizeof(ObjectInfo)` in place of `(DWORD)strlen(msg)` in Server, and in place of `sizeof(buffer) - 1` in Client. the problem got resolved.

From comments in the question from @RaymondChan, I have removed the null termination. Also since the size of the data is known to both the applications, that size can be used directly while sendinding `write` and receiving `read()`.

For better readibility, I have reordered the ObjectInfo structure.

**Fixed Client code:**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

#define TestCoordinate_Pipe "\\\\.\\pipe\\TestCoordinates"
#define MESSAGE_MAX_LENGTH  1024

typedef struct _ObjectInfo
{
    UINT32 Height;
    UINT32 Width;
    UINT32 XCoordinate;
    UINT32 YCoordinate;
}ObjectInfo;

char* getObjectLocation(char* pipe, char* buffer)
{
    HANDLE hPipe;
    DWORD dwRead;
    hPipe = CreateNamedPipe(
        pipe,
        PIPE_ACCESS_DUPLEX,
        PIPE_TYPE_BYTE | PIPE_READMODE_BYTE | PIPE_WAIT,
        1,
        MESSAGE_MAX_LENGTH,
        MESSAGE_MAX_LENGTH,
        NMPWAIT_USE_DEFAULT_WAIT,
        NULL);
    while (hPipe != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
    {
        if (ConnectNamedPipe(hPipe, NULL) != FALSE)   // wait for someone to connect to the pipe
        {
            while (ReadFile(hPipe, buffer, sizeof(ObjectInfo), &dwRead, NULL) != FALSE);
        }
        DisconnectNamedPipe(hPipe);
        hPipe = INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE;
    }
    return buffer;
}

int main()
{
    ObjectInfo objectInfo;
    char* buffer = NULL;
    buffer = malloc(MESSAGE_MAX_LENGTH + 1);
    memset(buffer, 0, MESSAGE_MAX_LENGTH + 1);
    getObjectLocation(TestCoordinate_Pipe, buffer);
    RtlCopyMemory(&objectInfo, buffer, sizeof(ObjectInfo));
    free(buffer);
    printf("\n\tHeight: %d;\t X-Coordinate: %d\t Y-Coordinate: %d\tWidth: %d",
        objectInfo.Height,
        objectInfo.Width,
        objectInfo.XCoordinate,
        objectInfo.YCoordinate);
}
```

**Fixed Server code:**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <Windows.h>

#define TestCoordinate_Pipe "\\\\.\\pipe\\TestCoordinates"
#define MESSAGE_MAX_LENGTH  1024

typedef struct _ObjectInfo
{
    UINT32 Height;
    UINT32 Width;
    UINT32 XCoordinate;
    UINT32 YCoordinate;
}ObjectInfo;

void setObjectLocation(char* pipe, char* msg)
{
    HANDLE hPipe;
    DWORD dwWritten;

    hPipe = CreateFile(
        pipe,
        GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE,
        0,
        NULL,
        OPEN_EXISTING,
        0,
        NULL);
    if (hPipe != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
    {
        WriteFile(
            hPipe,
            msg,
            sizeof(ObjectInfo),
            &dwWritten,
            NULL);
        CloseHandle(hPipe);
    }
}

int main()
{
    ObjectInfo objectInfo;
    objectInfo.Height = 0;
    objectInfo.Width = 1;
    objectInfo.XCoordinate = 2;
    objectInfo.YCoordinate = 3;


    printf("\n\tHeight: %d;\tWidth: %d\t X-Coordinate: %d\t Y-Coordinate: %d",
        objectInfo.Height,
        objectInfo.Width,
        objectInfo.XCoordinate,
        objectInfo.YCoordinate);

    char msg[MESSAGE_MAX_LENGTH] = { 0 };
    RtlCopyMemory(msg, &objectInfo, sizeof(ObjectInfo));
    setObjectLocation(TestCoordinate_Pipe, msg);
}
```

**The Learning:**

Namedpipes use `strlen()` to communicate the size of `string` buffer. Strings are null terminated, so the reader needs to add null termination. However while passing structure, the data is not of string type so using `strlen()` is not a good idea, it is better to use `sizeof()` operator to convey the lenght between namedpipe server and namedpipe client in C.